# Spring boot Database (Apache Derby) using CrudRepository gets erased everytime I relaunch the application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am just starting on a Spring Boot application. I am following [Java Brain's Spring Boot playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x) .

**Setup :** 
For CRUD operation I am using CrudRepository(`@Repository`) interface as parent interface with which the API are facilitated through Controller(`@RestController`) and Apache Derby is used as an embedded database for the application data (`@Entities`). The Bridging between `@RestController` and `@Repository` is done using a `@Service` annotated class.

**Problem :** 
Whenever I relaunch the Spring Boot app, I lose all the data that I had stored into my embedded database using `POST` `@RequestBody`. I have to do the `POST` request again if I want store some data into database.  Which clearly does not look like a good practice to me neither for development nor for production and I must be doing something wrong.

**Repo**  :

```
@Repository
public interface DailyRashifalRepository extends  
    CrudRepository<DailyRashifalEntity, String> {
}
```

**Entity** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="daily_rashifal")
public class DailyRashifalEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String rashifal;
    private int yr;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public DailyRashifalEntity(String id, String rashifal, int yr, int month, int day) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.rashifal = rashifal;
        this.yr = yr;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }

    private DailyRashifalEntity() {
        super();
    }
    //Getters and setters 
    // equals to and hascode overrides 
}
```

**Application :**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Service :**

```
@Service
public class RashifalService {

    @Autowired
    DailyRashifalRepository dailyRepo;
    @Autowired
    WeeklyRashifalRepository weeklyRepo;
    @Autowired
    MonthlyRashifalRepository monthlyRepo;
    @Autowired
    YearlyRashifalRepository yearlyRepo;



    public List<DailyRashifalEntity> getDailyAll(int year, int month, int day) {
        List<DailyRashifalEntity> rashiList = new ArrayList<DailyRashifalEntity>();
        dailyRepo.findAll().forEach(rashiList::add);
        return rashiList;
    }
    public DailyRashifalEntity getDaily( String id, int year, int month, int day) {
        return dailyRepo.findOne(id);
    }
    public void addDaily(DailyRashifalEntity entity) {
        dailyRepo.save(entity);
    }
    public void addDailyAll(List<DailyRashifalEntity> entityList) {
        for(int i=0;i<entityList.size();i++){
            dailyRepo.save(entityList.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void updateDaily(DailyRashifalEntity entity) {
        dailyRepo.save(entity);
    }
    .....Other methods 
}
```

**Controller :**

```
@RestController
public class RashifalController {

    @Autowired
    private RashifalService service;


    //Daily Rashifal API


    @RequestMapping("rashifal/daily")
    public List<DailyRashifalEntity> getDailyRashifalAll() {
        return service.getDailyAll(2017, 2, 3);
    }

    @RequestMapping("rashifal/daily/{id}")
    public DailyRashifalEntity getDailyRashifal(@PathVariable String id) {
        return service.getDaily(id,2017, 2, 3);
         /*DailyRashifalEntity entity = new DailyRashifalEntity("3", "Ramro Din", 2074, 2, 28);
         return entity;*/
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "rashifal/daily")
    public void addRashifalAll(@RequestBody List<DailyRashifalEntity> entityList) {
        service.addDailyAll(entityList);

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "rashifal/daily/")
    public void updateRashifalDailyAll(@RequestBody List<DailyRashifalEntity> entityList) {
        service.updateDailyAll(entityList);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "rashifal/daily/delete_all")
    public void deleteDailyAll(@RequestBody List<DailyRashifalEntity> entityList) {
        service.deleteDailyAll(entityList);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "rashifal/daily/delete_all_by_day/{year}/{month}/{day}")
    public void deleteDailyAllByDay(@PathVariable("year") int year, @PathVariable("month") int month,
            @PathVariable("day") int day) {
        service.deleteDailyAllByDay(year, month, day);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "rashifal/daily/delete_by_day/{id}/{year}/{month}/{day}")
    public void deleteDailyByDay( @PathVariable("id") String id,@PathVariable("year") int year,
            @PathVariable("month") int month, @PathVariable("day") int day) {
        service.deleteDailyByDay(id,year, month, day);
    }
}
```

**Pom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gurkhatech</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Spring boot api for rashifal REST api</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**Application.properties :**

```
server.port=8080 
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

What am I doing wrong? You can see all the code [here](https://github.com/erluxman/springdemo/archive/stackoverflow_question.zip) or you can see the code in [Github](https://github.com/erluxman/springdemo) (please  follow the Stack Overflow question release).

Comment: That is what embedded databases are designed for. It is only for testing and demo purposes. If you want to persist data, you need to move from derby to some other database. With springboot, it is quite easy to do so. Just setup a database (postgres or mysql) and then add that connection parameters in your application properties(along with necessary dependencies in your pom and also remove derby dependencies). The rest will be taken care of, no need to change anything in your code.

Comment: @pvpkiran thank you so much for the insightful answer, What I could ask more is  the possibility that you could provide me a good reference to follow ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a database to perist the data, H2 and Derby are embedded and require data to be coded into the db on boot. To add a simple MySQL database you would add this to your pom.xml:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

You will neeed to set your properties for the datasource in application.properties like so:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
# Everything after the ? is optional but I have found recommended previously.
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://serverip:3306/databasename?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
# Username and password
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

For references that I have previously found helpful when I first started have been the following:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic
and lots of Youtube videos and code from https://github.com/joshlong